# how can I import csv file without knowing table structure in PostgreSQL using pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a csv file to import in PostgreSQL . But I don't know the table structure and column names but as far I know I need those things to create the initial tables.
so I need to know that how can I determine the table structures  Please help me out!

Comment: You are going to have to determine that from the CSV file. Look at it and build a table schema that matches what you see.

Comment: What would you use the table for, if you didn't even know its structure?

Answer (score 1):

For this you need the list of fields, the list you can get by reading the first line of the csv file - there are functions that do this.
If you can read the file in JSON format, then with the functions json_object_keys and json_to_recordset you can create the table for any fields.